# Default folder sort options not honored when opened in another application

Tags: finder

I open finder, navigate to a folder and set my sort options to "last modified"

I then open chrome and go to some website where I can upload files. When I click a button that pops a finder window to select files and navigate to the same folder its sorted alphabetically.

Why isn't mac honoring my sort options for finder pop-out windows? Unlike MS Windows you also cant just change sort options inside of a file explorer window opened by another application- at least I could not find a way.

Comment: A Finder window is different than a File Chooser window, which looks an awful lot like a finder window with an OPEN and CANCEL button. 'File chooser' windows are set on a per application basis and often default to hard coded defaults set by the developer. It sounds like that is what you may be referring to.

Comment: ugh so its possible an application is popping a File Chooser window instead of a finder window? In this specific case is it possible to confirm if thats what chrome does? Is there a different setting for default sort options for File Chooser windows? this is a pita when I wanna upload a recent screenshot I took for example

Comment: A file-picker window only looks like a finder window, it's not one, though. File-picker Views are remembered per app, not per folder.

Comment: how do you set it for an app then? Could I set it, for example, for chrome? Is that totally app specific configuration or does the OS maintain a File-picker View per app mapping somewhere?

Comment: You set it, same as finder, by clicking the appropriate header… or are you in icon or column view? (For some reason I always assume everybody hates icon view as much as I do;) in which case there's a sort by drop menu - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA7VB.png